# Expose a Java Spring Boot method

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, gradle

I need to run a [Mongobee](https://github.com/mongobee/mongobee) method (so I can do a DB migration) from the command line. I have a Spring Boot + Gradle project.
What's the easiest way to expose that migration method to be run "from the outside", ie. command line?
Note: I need Spring DI, as show below (if not possible, please reply how to do it without DI).

```
@Autowired
Environment environment;

public Mongobee mongobee() {
  Mongobee runner = new Mongobee(mongodbConnectionString);
  runner.setDbName("yourDbName");
  runner.setChangeLogsScanPackage("com.expensesapp.changelogs");
  runner.setSpringEnvironment(environment)

  return runner;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirements correctly, you should be able to pass a JVM arg in and in your `@SpringBootApplication` main, grab whatever you need to pass in (I'm assuming that you're passing something in.. configuration or otherwise). Autowire MongoBee `@Autowired Mongobee mongobee` and call what you want on it from start up.

If you don't need to pass in an argument, you can just do this from the main without checking args - same steps, call your method in the main from the injected MongoBee